# customization cross-domain iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to get acceess to css in iFrame. I read some articles and questions on the SO. And all people say that this is impossible. Because this is other world.  I found the following example: [demo](http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Examples/CrossDomain/ParentPage.html)

Can somebody explains how it works and it's really cross-domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This page is made of three pages.

- Container ( http://shouldersofgiants.co.uk/Examples/CrossDomain/ParentPage.html)
- Top iframe ( http://www.pierslawson.webspace.virginmedia.com/Examples/CrossDomain/InnerFrame.html )
- Bottom iframe ( http://www.pierslawson.webspace.virginmedia.com/Examples/CrossDomain/InnerFrameProxy.html )

In order for all this to work, the contain page needs to push "messages", and the iframes need to listen to them.

On container page, changes get pushed around via

```
 var elem = document.getElementById('innerFrameProxy');
 elem.contentWindow.location = 'http://www.pie ... meProxy.html#' + message;
```

The iframe pages have

```
 function ForwardMessage() {
     var message = document.location.hash;
```

which is always ready pick up changes.

The iframes changed look and feel because they were setup to do so, it not because they forced to